# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] : Strange PDO error after server provider crash

Tags: php, pdo

After a crash server, we have a strange error with our database...

Password and user is correct, we use a simple PDO connect :

```
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databaseName', 'correctUSER','correctPassword');
    die('ok');
}
catch(Exception $e)`enter code here`
{
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

But we have a : "Error : SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'correctUSER'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" ??

We try to delete, recreate database and user but we have always the problem, the strange thing is that if we try we the root user => it works but it's not safe to use the root password...

Anyone have a solution ??

Thanks !

Comment: Remove the die('ok'); see what happens.

Comment: SO, you created a new user with `GRANT`, flushed privileges, etc.? In that case, check mysql error logs, check what `mysql_upgrade --force` does, possibly try a `REPAIR TABLE mysql.user`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error with mysql, I have to make a

REPAIR TABLE mysql.user

Answer (score -2):

Nothing actually strange in this error. The answer is quite simple and obvious.

> Password and user is correct

As you can see from the error message below, this statement of yours is simply not true.
So, to solve that problem you have to supply correct username and password.

Also just a side note: remove that try-catch-die stuff from your code. It's totally useless, redundant and insecure.

Comment: Not it's not as simple as that !

We found the solution, we have to delete the anonym user with the % access (=> it's a bug when your server crash)